# Como incrementar chaves primárias e estrangeiras no PostgreSQL usando SERIAL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Não consigo **incrementar automaticamente as chaves primárias e estrangeiras** das minhas tabelas usando **SERIAL**, pois acontece erro e sempre tenho que inserir o valor das chaves.

```
create table cliente(
    cd_cliente serial primary key not null,
    nome varchar(50),
    endereco varchar(50),
    cidade varchar(50)
)

create table telefone(
    cd_telefone serial primary key not null,
    cd_cliente serial,
    numero_telefone varchar(20),
    foreign key(cd_cliente) references cliente (cd_cliente)
)

insert into cliente
values
(1, 'Pessoa1', 'Algum lugar', 'Cidade'),
(2, 'Pesso2', 'Algum lugar', 'Cidade'),
(3, 'Pessoa3', 'Algum lugar', 'Cidade')

insert into telefone
values
(1, 1, '01 1111-1111'),
(2, 2, '02 2222-2222'),
(3, 3, '03 3333-3333')
```

Comment: Se  você definiu o campo `cd_telefone`como `serial` então não informe um valor para este campo ou informe `DEFAULT` para que seja considerado o valor gerado pela `sequence`. Como já foi dito não tem sentido definir `telefone.cd_cliente` como `serial`já que você sempre deve informar a qual ciente está associado o telefone.

Answer (score 0):

Na tabela 'cliente' deveria funcionar, na tabela 'telefone' acho que está errado classificar cd_cliente como serial, deveria ser inteiro, afinal é o código do cliente que deve constar do INSERT, não deve ser um número gerado automaticamente.